# How best can I explain the professional ethics of GenAI to students?

Tags: generative-ai

Recently, a decision was made to allow the removal of AI-generated content in response to a letter from Moderators [at Stack Exchange](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/). This type of AI-generated content is increasingly used in response to LLMs such as ChatGPT being widely available for free. Professionals also need to be aware that the technology allows for AI-generated text to be created easily for publications without author effort beyond prompting.

Because these concepts are important to understand, but I have had difficulty communicating them, I am interested in how to explain some of the pros and cons of the complex morality of GenAI. By this, I mean the use of a tool such as ChatGPT to answer questions, edit posts, or even make administrative decisions. I am looking for a non-technical answer, but it could include some of the mechanics, such as a description of processes (the what more than the how). This also seems to be something of a problem more generally based on the existance of Incubators such as [ECCRI](https://europeancyber.org/).

I find some good anecdotes in response to [this closed Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391485/can-we-experiment-to-use-ai-for-moderators#comment1308750_391488). Still, I am curious how to explain the complex answers I find covered in that response simply to students who do not have professional experience yet.

I am not asking if there should be GenAI content allowed on SE - but instead, why it is not done (appropriate as an explanation for an undergraduate student in information technology). This example may help point to issues in the broader area of GenAI use. I see three main issues I would like feedback on how to address:

#### No Professional Code of Ethics

The answer that it is against professional codes is good, but without lived experience, the consequences of going against these can seem intangible to students.

*For example*, a concept like misuse of Personally Identifiable Information by a generative AI is too far removed from the immediacy to solve the problem. For the most part, they haven't been victims of this type of crime yet.

#### AI is viewed as accurate

Presenting examples of [hacks](https://github.com/0xk1h0/ChatGPT_DAN) or hallucinations also leads to the argument that *“we will make it better.”* They minimize the errors.

Similarly, when I go down the [strong vs weak](https://www.ibm.com/topics/strong-ai) argument, it is not clear that a distinction exists between what they are seeing/using, and they dismiss the difference. They think Furby is conscious. **The students do not understand that the AI is effective only at what it is trained to produce**.

#### The facts are uncomfortable

It is also possible that some of the difficulty in teaching the material stems from a [cognitive conflict](https://www.apa.org/education-career/k12/misconceptions) since many of the students have grown up with the type of recommendation algorithms already assumed as a part of life.

In my opinion, all these expanations miss what I feel to be a sort of instinctual humanistic [Great Revolt](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Butlerian_Jihad) in a lot of the responses I read in researching the morality of using GenAI. Sorry, I'm not sure how to phrase the underlying assumption I perceive in response to the idea of machines replacing people other than a reference to Science Fiction worst-case scenarios. I want to convey this ideal of what Sara Baase calls a [Gift of Fire](https://www.pearson.com/en-us/subject-catalog/p/gift-of-fire-a-social-legal-and-ethical-issues-for-computing-technology/P200000003177?view=educator).

But the preservation of human creativity (leadership) alongside the support of computers is something that I feel like is worth teaching—and wonder if anyone has written, read, seen, etc. a work that would convey this at an entry-level. The responses [in this GenAI question](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/59/to-what-extent-can-genai-be-used-for-content-moderation) are close to what I am seeking, but there still is a level of complexity I would like to simplify and address the specific issues mentioned above. Another source might be [ACM Software Engineering Code of Ethics](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/265684.265699), but again the issue of lived experience limits this. Just throwing out some ideas to try and explain what I have tried in the past.